# Keychain access in iOS: "Keychain failed to store the value with code: -50"

Tags: ios, error-handling, keychain, error-code

I don't find the information regarding such error code when calling `SecItemAdd`, what could be causing it?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** This is the function where I get the error:

```
+ (BOOL)storeWithKey:(NSString *)keyStr withValueStr:(NSString *)valueStr
{
   if ((keyStr != nil) && (![keyStr isEqualToString:@""]) &&
       (valueStr != nil) && (![valueStr isEqualToString:@""])) {

       NSData *valueData = [valueStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
       NSString *service = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];

       NSDictionary *secItem = @{(__bridge id)kSecClass : (__bridge id)kSecClassInternetPassword,
                              (__bridge id)kSecAttrService : service,
                              (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount : keyStr,
                              (__bridge id)kSecValueData : valueData};

       CFTypeRef result = NULL;

       // Store value and get the result code
       OSStatus status = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)secItem, &result);

       NSLog(@"'writeToKeychain'. %@", [self getErrorMessage:status]);

       return [self checkIfInKeychain:status];
   }
   else {
       return NO;
   }
}
```

Comment: where did u get this error?

Comment: -50 = paramErr. Some of the parameters in your call are wrong, the call cannot possibly succeed because of the incorrect parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-50` means `One or more parameters passed to a function were not valid`. You're wrong combination of parameters.

If you use `kSecAttrService` and `kSecAttrAccount`, `kSecClass` should be `kSecClassGenericPassword`.

```
NSDictionary *secItem = @{(__bridge id)kSecClass : (__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword,
                          (__bridge id)kSecAttrService : service,
                          (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount : keyStr,
                          (__bridge id)kSecValueData : valueData};
```

If you use `kSecClassInternetPassword` as `kSecClass`, you should use `kSecAttrServer` and `kSecAttrPort` (If needed) instead `kSecAttrService`.

```
NSDictionary *secItem = @{(__bridge id)kSecClass : (__bridge id)kSecClassInternetPassword,
                          (__bridge id)kSecAttrServer : @"example.com",
                          (__bridge id)kSecAttrPort : @(80), // Optional
                          (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount : keyStr,
                          (__bridge id)kSecValueData : valueData};
```

Comment: This solved a similar issue for me in Swift 3.  Same code in ObjC without kSecClass works, but in Swift 3 it gives -50.  Added kSecClass with kSecClassGenericPassword and it works.  Thanks @kishikawa-katsumi

Comment: How app will make a contact when it's in lock state.

Comment: @kishikawa I tried using your app and it will not be able to provide content stored in app keychain. Is this something happening randomly or just happened straightaway.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for the error codes are in the `Security/SecBase.h` file. You can find them at the end.

You can also find them referenced by the documentation to `SecItemAdd`. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000898-CH5g-CJBEABHG